# Jump to Anchor using Mod-Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, anchor

I designed my Website as OnePage Design. However, I want to keep using my old URLs. To navigate within my new Website I'm using anchors.

I do not get Mod-Rewrite working using anchors.

The URLs I want to rewrite

```
www.mywebsite.com/nameOfAnchor
www.mywebsite.com/nameOfAnchor/
```

To be:

```
www.mywebsite.com/index.php?#nameOfAnchor
```

I don't get this working using the following code (Only calls index.php but does not navigate to the anchor)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /[^.]+[^/](|/)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?#$1 [NE]
```

The rule is working well if I want to hand over a variable via get

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /[^.]+[^/](|/)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?variable=$1 [NE]
```

But this does not solve my problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: @anubhava well, I'd like to use display the URLs without the `#`. The URL will be changed via Javascript while clicking on anchors within the page to the new structure...

Comment: Anchor or `#` has no relevance on server side so rewrite won't help.

Answer (score 0):

You need external redirects.

```
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php$)[^/]+/?$ /#$0 [NS,NE,B,L,R=301]
```